# Override Spring properties with VM options

Tags: java, spring

I want to achieve the following behavior:

I use property files with Spring `ResourceBundleMessageSource` with properties like this:

```
my.prop=42
```

Now I want to override properties with VM options like this:

```
-Dmy.prop=13
```

How can I do this in a simple and transparent way?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use your MessageSource only for language Strings.

Use property files for properties.

Now you can load your properties files with org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer

In your XML, instead of using the default value which is SYSTEM_PROPERTIES_MODE_FALLBACK, set it to use SYSTEM_PROPERTIES_MODE_OVERRIDE.

You can now load your props using the @Value annotations, and the VM options will override the values you set in your properties file

Example:

So call your MessageSource messages.properties

```
<bean id="messageSource" class="org.springframework.context.support.ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource">
    <property name="basename" value="classpath:messages"/>
    <property name="fileEncodings" value="UTF-8"/>
    <property name="defaultEncoding" value="UTF-8"/>
</bean>
```

And call your properties file misspiggy.properties (or something else :))

```
<bean id="propertyLoader" class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer">
    <property name="ignoreResourceNotFound" value="false"/>
    <property name="systemPropertiesModeName" value="SYSTEM_PROPERTIES_MODE_OVERRIDE"/>
    <property name="fileEncoding" value="UTF-8"/>
    <property name="locations">
        <list>
            <value>classpath:misspiggy.properties</value>
        </list>
    </property>
</bean>
```

Comment: Yes, I can use SPeL to get the VM props but when I leave out the property I get a `SpelEvaluationException`: `Field or property 'myProp' cannot be found on object of type 'java.util.Properties'`. What I need is a fallback in the property file. I just want to read the standard properties from file, but when I set a VM option, then the value from the properties file should be overridden. When I not set the VM option the value from the file should be used.

Comment: Sorry I just edited my answer. I think my edit should work for you :)

Comment: And it works also for dot notation like `my.prop`. I have extended my `PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer` bean with the property `<property name="systemPropertiesModeName" value="SYSTEM_PROPERTIES_MODE_OVERRIDE"/>` and now it works. Thanks!